# return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-deployment

I was making one webapp in django. I try to deployed it on pythonanywhere everything was going fine but in last when i tried to collect static files using `python manage.py collectstatic` it is giving me this error:

```
return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

suggest some idea how can I solve it.

Here is my setting.py file

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '!25%rdt-$_$bsc*fl)e7x2*x6awjca^3_2t-k@l0tu*8k!f33&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'static/')
```

Answer (score 21):

If you are using Django v3.1 then you can try placing `str()` around the database path in the `settings.py` file. This is because SQLite only accepts strings and Django v3.1 `settings.py` returns a `pathlib.Path` object.

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I had the same problem and found the answer here:
https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-tutorial-python-manage-py-startapp-polls-fails/2718

Comment: thanks...worked for me. i was trying to port over to django 3

Comment: thank you for this answer. I was very confused.

Answer (score 5):

#in settings.py do

```py
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

**Here is the issue**:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Both `type(BASE_DIR)` and `type(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')` are `<class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a typo, instead ',' used '/'.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using the latest Django v3.1
I got this issue because I forgot to activate the virtual environment